# Why is Android Studio showing me all this info about my phone in the log?

Tags: android-studio, logcat, android-debug, usb-debugging

I have been using Android Studio for a month, plugging my phone (Asus Zenfone 5 if relevant) in USB to launch my app in debug mode. I had to enable "USB debug" on my phone in order to do that.
First, I had no issues, everything worked fine.
I stopped working on the app for a few weeks, now that I am back at it, whenever I plug my phone, even when I don't launch my Android app, the log shows constant info about my phone. 
It seems really random to me, I don't know if I should post the actuals logs or if there could be some informations that I don't want to share on the internet.
It shows lines about Facebook or Google, and it keeps displaying the state of my accelerometer...

1- this is confusing, is there something wrong happening ?

2- it makes it very hard to debug my actual app because the relevant logs are lost in the mass

Do you have any clue, tips that would help me understand/solve this ?
Thank you in advance :)

Examples of lines I get in the log (the first bit shows up every second or so, the second part shows up quite randomly and the content varies a lot) :

```
2020-05-07 21:58:09.376 734-1143/? E/ALSPS_HAL: [Sensor_HAL] LightSensor: light=211.000000 (211)
2020-05-07 21:58:09.412 734-1143/? E/ALSPS_HAL: [Sensor_HAL] LightSensor: light=375.000000 (375)
2020-05-07 21:58:09.794 734-1141/? E/qti_sensors_hal: [SSC_HAL] ACCEL, X:-0.50 Y:2.74 Z:9.52
2020-05-07 21:58:10.794 734-1141/? E/qti_sensors_hal: [SSC_HAL] ACCEL, X:-0.69 Y:2.84 Z:9.51
2020-05-07 21:58:11.575 734-1143/? E/ALSPS_HAL: [Sensor_HAL] FRGBSensor: CCT=2477.000000, R raw=1555.000000 , G raw=575.000000 , B raw=188.000000 , IR raw=7.000000
```

````
2020-05-07 21:51:14.912 6544-6609/? I/mobileconfig: Using asset manager to stream (sessionless: YES) params_map.txt
2020-05-07 21:51:14.957 6544-6609/? I/mobileconfig: Params map streaming - readbytes: 413966/413966
2020-05-07 21:51:14.957 6544-6609/? I/mobileconfig: Successfully parsed (sessionless: YES) params_map.txt
2020-05-07 21:51:14.965 6544-6609/? I/mobileconfig: Initialized MobileConfig - directory: /data/user/0/com.facebook.orca/files, appVersion: 263.0.0.18.125, paramHash: e30a3449fd31085b0a179785466927b8, readOnly: false bufferPathPostfix: 
2020-05-07 21:51:14.971 6544-6569/? W/msgr.MultiSignalANRDetector: Pausing error state checks
2020-05-07 21:51:15.270 3309-3346/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires com.facebook.permission.prod.FB_APP_COMMUNICATION due to registered receiver BroadcastFilter{e35a060 u0 ReceiverList{7380c63 6544 com.facebook.orca/10083/u0 remote:67e6a92}}
2020-05-07 21:51:15.270 3309-3346/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.net.conn.INET_CONDITION_ACTION flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires com.facebook.permission.prod.FB_APP_COMMUNICATION due to registered receiver BroadcastFilter{e35a060 u0 ReceiverList{7380c63 6544 com.facebook.orca/10083/u0 remote:67e6a92}}
2020-05-07 21:51:15.303 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.browser.lite.BrowserLiteIntentService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.304 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.browser.lite.BrowserLiteInMainProcessIntentService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.304 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.common.errorreporting.memory.MemoryDumpUploadService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.304 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.contacts.service.ContactLocaleChangeService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.304 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.messaging.chatheads.service.ChatHeadsBooterService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.304 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsJobService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.304 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.analytics.appstatelogger.AppStateIntentService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.304 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.analytics2.logger.LollipopUploadService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.304 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.appcomponentmanager.AppComponentManagerService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.305 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.appupdate.DownloadCompleteService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.306 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.common.dextricks.DexOptimization$Service is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.306 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.common.dextricks.DexOptimizationJobService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.306 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.conditionalworker.ConditionalWorkerService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.306 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.delayedworker.DelayedWorkerService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.306 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceJobIntentService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.307 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.googleplay.GooglePlayInstallRefererService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.307 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.messaging.prefs.notifications.NotificationPrefsSyncService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.307 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.messaging.sms.defaultapp.SmsHandlerService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.307 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.messaging.universallinks.receiver.InstallReferrerFetchJobIntentService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.307 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.orca.notify.MessagesNotificationService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.307 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.oxygen.preloads.sdk.firstparty.managedappcache.IsManagedAppCacheJobService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.307 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.push.registration.RegistrarHelperService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.308 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.push.crossapp.PackageRemovedReporterService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.308 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.push.adm.ADMService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.308 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.push.adm.ADMBroadcastReceiverJobBase is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.308 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.push.adm.ADMJobIntentService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.309 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.push.fbpushdata.common.FbPushDataHandlerService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.309 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.push.fcm.FcmRegistrarFbJobIntentService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.309 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.push.mqtt.service.MqttPushHelperService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.309 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.push.negativefeedback.PushNegativeFeedbackFbJobIntentService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.309 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.reportaproblem.base.bugreport.BugReportUploadService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.309 6544-6610/? W/msgr.ServiceInfoParser: X.2LH: Service com.facebook.selfupdate2.SelfUpdateLaterWaiterService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
2020-05-07 21:51:15.318 3309-3346/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires com.facebook.permission.prod.FB_APP_COMMUNICATION due to registered receiver BroadcastFilter{3950bbf u0 ReceiverList{7149dde 6544 com.facebook.orca/10083/u0 remote:df2b919}}
2020-05-07 21:51:15.413 6544-6610/? W/msgr.lacrima: FbErrorReportingConfig.earlyInit wasn't called.
2020-05-07 21:51:15.467 6544-6610/? I/zygote: Deoptimizing X.0jq X.0gZ.A0D(long, java.lang.Integer) due to JIT inline cache```
````

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing to worry about! Most apps are constantly outputting TONS of data, by default Android Studio shows everything from every app.

If I plug mine in, there's always 4-5 applications spewing out errors, and countless info messages.

In your Logcat, set your application as the debug application (where it says "No debuggable processes" in the screenshot) and filter only to it ("Show only selected application").

You can also add your package name into the search field, but this is much less accurate as some of your logs won't contain your package name. It will also show logs from your launcher / the OS when it installs / uninstalls your app.

[image: logcat for own app]